# как найти и вытащить новые добавленные объекты в json на PHP?

Tags: php, массивы, json, объекты

**json1**

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "data": {
   "accountid": [
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 5
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 15
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 18
 }
         ]
     }
 }
```

**Json2**

```
{
 "status": "ok",
 "data": {
   "accountid": [
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 5
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 8
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 11
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 15
 },
 {
 "all": {
 "wins": 7,
 "losses": 1,
 "battles": 8
 },
 "id": 18
 }
        ]
    }
 }
```

Во втором json файле добавились новые объекты в массив, номера id всегда рандомные, в данном случае, именно id 8 и 11 со значениями в [all]. Именно эти значения и нужно вытащить. Как найти решение?

должно получиться так: Изменения между 1 и 2 json - добавлены id 8 и id 11.

В предыдущем моем вопросе я написал код ([Сравнение двух json php и запись в третий](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084363/%d0%a1%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%85-json-php-%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%b9)), но он работает, только когда 2 разных json идентичны по ид.

Если возможно, подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**PHP**:

```
$json1 = '{"status": "ok", "data": {"accountid": [{"all": {"wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 5 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 15 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 18 }]}}';
$json2 = '{"status": "ok", "data": {"accountid": [{"all": {"wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 5 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 8 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 11 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 15 }, { "all": { "wins": 7, "losses": 1, "battles": 8 }, "id": 18 }]}}';

$arr1 = json_decode($json1,true); // переводим первый и второй json в массивы
$arr2 = json_decode($json2,true);
$existIDs = array(); // пустой массив для создания списка существующих в первом массиве ID


foreach ($arr1["data"]["accountid"] as $exist) {
    $existIDs[] = $exist['id']; // записываем все ID из первого json в массив
}

foreach ($arr2["data"]["accountid"] as $key => $toremove) { // проводим цикл по второму массиву
    if (in_array($toremove['id'],$existIDs)) { // проверяем, существует ли во втором массиве элемент с ID, существующим в первом массиве
        echo "Уничтожаем элемент с ID: ".$toremove['id']." (порядковый номер: ".$key.")".PHP_EOL; // комментарии для отладки, при релизе уберите
        unset($arr2["data"]["accountid"][$key]); // если существует, удаляем этот элемент из второго массива
    }
}

echo PHP_EOL."ID оставшихся элементов:".PHP_EOL;
foreach($arr2["data"]["accountid"] as $arr) {
    echo "- ".$arr['id'].PHP_EOL;
}

echo PHP_EOL."Структура массива без повторяющихся элементов:".PHP_EOL;
print_r($arr2);
```

**Вывод**:

```
Уничтожаем элемент с ID: 5 (порядковый номер: 0)
Уничтожаем элемент с ID: 15 (порядковый номер: 3)
Уничтожаем элемент с ID: 18 (порядковый номер: 4)

ID оставшихся элементов:
- 8
- 11

Структура массива без повторяющихся элементов:
Array (
  [status] => ok
  [data] => Array (
    [accountid] => Array (
      [1] => Array (
        [all] => Array (
          [wins] => 7
          [losses] => 1
          [battles] => 8
        ) // End of [all]
        [id] => 8
      ) // End of [1]
      [2] => Array (
        [all] => Array (
          [wins] => 7
          [losses] => 1
          [battles] => 8
        ) // End of [all]
        [id] => 11
      ) // End of [2]
    ) // End of [accountid]
  ) // End of [data]
) // End
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо Dmitry за помощь, я нашел свое решение, выкладываю код ниже. Я не пониманию людей, которые мне минусы поставили, вместо того, чтобы написать комментарий как и где искать зацепку, но и им спасибо, ведь они мотивировали меня до последнего самому найти решение.

```
$jsonnum = json_decode(file_get_contents('1.json'), true);
$jsonnum1 = json_decode(file_get_contents('2.json'), true);

 foreach ($jsonnum['data']['accountid'] as $k => $v)
 {
  foreach ($jsonnum1['data']['accountid'] as $k1 => $v1)
  {
$part[$k] = $v['id']; 
$part1[$k1] = $v1['id']; 
  }
 }
$missed = array_diff(array_values($part1), $part); 
print_r($missed);
```